# How to integrate a tolerance?

Tags: python, counter

I have a binary list `sequence` and when there is a 1 it means that the user was active that day and a 0 when he wasn't. I want to count how often a week there was a 1 in the list (so, the number of ones in every 7 positions). I use

```
for d in range(0,len(sequence),7):
    b=sequence[d:d+7].count(1) 
    a.append(b)
```

The list `a` has the length of how many weeks the user was active and he has to be at least 2 times a week active. Because of holidays and illness I want to integrate a tolerance where the entry of `a` could be smaller than 2 for a certain number of times. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Of course this is possible. What exactly was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: I have no idea for a command to begin ..

Comment: Well, you have to do something similar to `a` as you did for `sequence`. Instead of counting how many 1s there are, you have to count the 2s or 3s or whatever you have in mind.

Comment: Yesss! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Counter` class

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(a)

if c[1] + c[0] > your_tolerance:
     print('Not active enough !')
```